# Neocomplete conflict with auto line-breaking in vim

Tags: arch-linux, vim

I've found a conflict between automatic line breaks in vim and the neocomplete Vundle plugin. When neocomplete is off, then my `set textwidth=80` option works correctly, i.e. a line break is inserted automatically when I type past the 80 character limit.

However, when neocomplete is activated, it doesn't work as I'd expect. When I type past 80 characters, the line doesn't automatically break, and I keep typing beyond that limit. Then, when I hit `Enter`, the hard line breaks are inserted where they should've been automatically been inserted previously, and my cursor ends up one line below all of the newly formatted text.

I went through my `.vimrc` and changed the different options I had set for neocomplete but found that none of them seemed to cause the issue. Merely turning neocomplete on results in this behavior.

I'm running arch-linux, which I just switched to a little over a week ago. I was running Xbuntu before that, and I had neocomplete working with no such issues. Here's my `.vimrc`: http://pastebin.com/A4H9E0SA

Can anyone replicate this issue with neocomplete and/or have any ideas as to how to fix this without completely removing the plugin?

Comment: See this issue on the bug tracker, here: https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/issues/345